# Cocoa: Prevent activation of app when handling a custom URL scheme?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, url-scheme

I have a Cocoa app that registers a custom URL scheme: `myapp://dostuff`. When the URL is opened (for example from Safari), my app receives the event and handles the URL.

So far so good. Now the problem is that my app is activated and its windows move to the foreground covering Safari from which the custom URL was clicked. I'd like Safari to remain active and handle the custom URL in my application in the background.

Is this possible?

**My use case:** When the custom URL is clicked in Safari, I'd like to show a popup menu above Safari with a number of options. Only once the user picks an option from the menu do I want my app to move to the foreground.

Comment: I don't think that's possible .... but what you can do is to do a web page which shows an alert with options and if user selects option to open the app you redirect it to custom URL scheme: `myapp://dostuff ` of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that's not an option, because I need data from my app (i.e. the menu entries) before I can show the menu.

Comment: Perhaps providing a [Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/) with your app is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible.** Custom URI schemes are used for moving between apps — there is no option of 'loading in the background'.

You have two workarounds:

1. Use a backend that can supply the data you need directly to the website, rather than trying to bring it through the local app.
2. Open the app from the page as you are currently doing, and then give the option to the user once the app is launched. A deep linking platform like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) can help with this.